# PDO fails on beginTransaction()

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to understand why this code fails:

```
<?php

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db', 'root', 'pass');

$db->beginTransaction();
if ($db->exec('select VERSION();') === FALSE) {
    $db->rollback();
}
$db->commit();
```

After executing this code I got 3-4 sec freeze then browser shows me

```
Error 103 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED): Unknown error.
```

something is wrong with my PDO extention, but i can't find any errors about what's wrong. 
Any ideas?

Comment: What error is shown in PHP error log?

Comment: or even more interesting: the mysql server log, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/error-log.html

Comment: Ohh, these logs (php and mysql) were clear. But I have found the problem. Stupid one...I recently updated PHP on my windows machine, but I forgot to update php5ts.dll in %windows%\system32 directory. For some reasons Apache was ok working with old php5ts.dll, but not with PDO extention. I found it when I look at windows event log -- apache was throwing application error. Thanks for you help anyway